# NG-Include Pass Element By ID

Tags: angularjs

In my code below I have repeated the outer div with ng-repeat, and included an external html template to have unique content inside the inner div. It works actually as expected in case I have many templates, however I am wondering if I can have only one template, and include its unique content by id or somehow else.

The code which works fine with multiple templates:

```
<body  ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">

<div id="outer" ng-repeat="tpl in ctrl.templates">
    <div id="inner" ng-include="tpl.template"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('myCtrl', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.templates = [
            {template: 'template1.htm'},
            {template: 'template2.htm'}
        ]
    }]);
</script>
</body>
```

The desired code:

```
<div id="outer" ng-repeat="tpl in ctrl.templates">
    <div id="inner" ng-include="tpl.template"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('myCtrl', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.templates = [
            {template: 'template1.htm'} //only one template which include different data enclosed to divs with unique id
        ]
    }]);
</script>
</body>
```

template1.html

```
<div class="template" id="template">
    <p>
        Content From Template
    </p>
</div>
<div class="template" id="template2">
    <p>
        Content From Template 2
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: So your desired code doesn't work?

Comment: No it does't. I need the code to repeat outer block, having unique content. The desired code just includes all content from template to the outer div which is not repeating.

Comment: Can you show the template?